# Add gridview nested dropdown.selectedValue to database

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have two tables relevant to this question...

```
tblCellTechnology
  CellTechnologyID, PK
  Description
  CellName

tblActionSchedule
  ActionID, PK
  ActionPhase
  ActionPeriod
  CellTechnology, FK
```

I have a bulk edit grid view with text boxes displaying the ActionID, Phase, Period and a dropdownlist linked directly to the CellTechnologyID from tblCellTechnology (as per image). I also have another textbox displaying the cell name based on the value in tblScheduleAction.CellTechnologyID (ActionDescription is pulled from another table).

How can I get the selected value from the ddl and write that to tblScheduleAction.CellTechnologyID? When I hard add a CellTechnologyID to tblScheduleActionID, the cellname textbox displays the correct value. I just need to be able to store the ddl.SelectedValue to tblScheduleAction.CellTechnologyID. I am using masterpages and sqldatasources to handle the inserting/updating/deleting of records.

I want the celltechnologyid column in the bottom gridview to display the list of potential celltechnologyid, it does as it is directly linked to that column from the top grid view, the selected value should also be stored in tblScheduleAction.CellTechnologyID. The cellname column should display the respective cellname. 
As they say, a picture is worth a thousand words...  https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Uhd.jpg

Comment: The table names you have stipulated in your question do not match those in your table definitions? What do you mean by 'hard add'?

Comment: @FastGeek I mean adding it in the database directly. The names are all correct, some headings are just changed for reading clarity.

Comment: I think your problem is probably very simple, but the way in which you have changed the words around when referencing tables and columns makes the actual question very confusing. Have you tried retrieving the selected value of the drop down list and feeding it as a parameter to an insert method in the relevant SqlDataSource?. If you want help with code then you will need to publish your code here so that people can see what you have done so far, and the structure of your pages.

Comment: @FastGeek To update, I compare the current items in the gridview, with the original items, then update the rows that have changed. My update statement looks like `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateP69]
(
   @ActionID int --tblActionLU
   ,@ActionDescription nvarchar(512) --tblActionLU
   ,@ActionPeriod int --tblScheduleAction
   ,@ActionPhase nvarchar(50) --tblScheduleAction
   ,@CellTechnologyID int --tblScheduleAction
) AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION`

Comment: @FastGeek `UPDATE tblScheduleAction
SET  tblScheduleAction.ActionPeriod = @ActionPeriod, tblScheduleAction.ActionPhase = @ActionPhase, tblScheduleAction.CellTechnologyID = @CellTechnologyID
FROM tblScheduleAction tbl1, tblActionLU tbl2
WHERE tbl1.ActionID = @ActionID
--WHERE tbl1.ActionID = @ActionID AND tbl1.CellTechnologyID = @CellTechnologyID


IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
 ROLLBACK
 RETURN
END

UPDATE tblActionLU
SET ActionDescription = @ActionDescription
WHERE ActionID = @ActionID

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
 ROLLBACK
 RETURN
END`

Comment: If a row has been identified as being changed, UpdateRow is called on the gridview and that update statement is used. My complete code behind is snipt.org/zigfh0, and aspx page snipt.org/zigfg9

Comment: So where in your code is the problem located - inside the 'P69IsRowModified' function or elsewhere? Update your question and describe what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By nested gridviews, I assume you are referring to a child gridview inside each parent gridview row. Getting values of child gridview controls is pretty easy.

> How can I get the selected value from the ddl and write that to tblScheduleAction.CellTechnologyID?

1. You use `FindControl` to find childgridview in say a `foreach` loop on your save records
2. You would then use find control to find the dropdownlists & save to your database

Check working example (Aspx)

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NestedGridviews.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.NestedGridviews" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="gvParent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="CategoryID" DataSourceID="sdsParentGrid" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" 
                    SortExpression="CategoryName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                            DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="sdsChildGrid">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" 
                                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" 
                                    SortExpression="ProductName" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="SupplierID" HeaderText="SupplierID" 
                                    SortExpression="SupplierID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" 
                                    SortExpression="CategoryID" />
                                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Discontinued" HeaderText="Discontinued" 
                                    SortExpression="Discontinued" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="My DropDown Column">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server">
                                            <asp:ListItem>Potatoes</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Tomatoes</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Mangoes</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsChildGrid" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName], [SupplierID], [CategoryID], [Discontinued] FROM [Alphabetical list of products] WHERE ([CategoryID] = @CategoryID)">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryID" Type="Int32" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsParentGrid" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [CategoryName], [Description] FROM [Categories] ORDER BY [CategoryName]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" onclick="btnSave_Click" 
        Text="Save to Database" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class NestedGridviews : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                GridView gvChild = e.Row.FindControl("gvChildGrid") as GridView;
                SqlDataSource sdsTemp = e.Row.FindControl("sdsChildGrid") as SqlDataSource;
                if (sdsTemp!=null)
                {
                    sdsTemp.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = gvParent.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["CategoryID"].ToString();
                    if (gvChild != null)
                    {
                        gvChild.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow growParent in gvParent.Rows)
            {
                // Find child gridview for each row
                GridView gvChild = growParent.FindControl("gvChildGrid") as GridView;
                if (gvChild != null)
                {
                    // use a foreach loop to find your control
                    foreach (GridViewRow growChild in gvChild.Rows)
                    {
                        DropDownList ddlTemp = growChild.FindControl("ddlTest") as DropDownList;
                        if (ddlTemp != null)
                        {
                            Response.Write(ddlTemp.SelectedValue.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]